# Access controller scope function in factory angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller, and a factory that is using the controller's functions. The reason I do this, is because I want to use some functionalities in more controllers, depending on the actual `$scope`
My solution would be something lik the code below. However, angular throws an error saying `controllerFunction` is undefined

**EDIT: This code is working! I made a typo somewhere else in the code.**

```
angular.module('myApp')
 .controller('myController', function ($scope, $http, myInterface) {
    var myFactory = new myInterface($scope);
    $scope.controllerFunction = function(){
        // do something 
    }
 })
 .factory('myInterface', function(){
    var self;
    function Interface($scope) {
      this.$scope = $scope;
      self = this;
    }

    Interface.prototype.interfaceFunction = function(){
      self.$scope.controllerFunction(); 
    }
    return Interface;
});
```

Comment: You can move `controllerFunction()` function to an specific service.. Than you can use it everywhere

Comment: are you  trying to call $scope.controllerFunction from your factory?

Comment: @Ved Yes, I try to call it.

Comment: This is a simplified code, the actual code is a lot more complex. Basically I have to implement a function in the `factory` that calls a function from `Controller1` and then call this factory-function in `Controller2`

Comment: @DNagy Please check my answer and let me know if it works for you

Comment: usually its the controller that access factory functions. Are you sure this is what you need?

Comment: @Ved I resolved the problem. It was a typo. But you got my upvote ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a callback method to your factory method from controller.

```
angular.module('myApp')
 .controller('myController', function ($scope, $http, myInterface) {
    myInterface.myMethod(function (){// callback method passed to factory
       $scope.controllerFunction();//will get called from factory via callback
   )}
    $scope.controllerFunction = function(){
        // do something 
    }
 })
 .factory('myInterface', function(){
     var myMethod = function (cb) {
        //your code
        cb();  //calling callback method of controller
     }

  return myMethod;

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, The problem with your code is you are passing the `$scope`, but after that you are defining the function. Note: `$scope is an object` and not a service which is singleton shared across. Each and every `controller` has its own `$scope`.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, NameService) {

    $scope.callController = function(){console.log("Called controller")};
    $scope.NameService = new NameService($scope);     
});

myApp.factory('NameService', function() {

    //constructor
    function NameService(scope) {
        this._scope = scope;
        this._someFunction()
    }

    //wherever you'd reference the scope
    NameService.prototype._someFunction = function() {
        this._scope.callController();
    }

    return NameService;

});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/5gmnvL6b/